# Null pointer exception in selenium webdriver - TestNG - PageFactory

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng

I am trying to automate using selenium webdriver, testng and page factory. But I am facing null pointer exception.

```
public class BrowserOpenClose extends Common {
    public WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeTest
    @Parameters("browser")
    public void initBrowser(String browser) {
        if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("FF")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette", "./gecko/geckodriver.exe");
            driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
        } else if (browser.equalsIgnoreCase("CH")) {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./chrome/chromedriver.exe");
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("https://www.flipkart.com/");
        }
    }

    @AfterTest
    public void closeBrowser() {
        waitUntil(10);
        driver.quit();
    }
}

    public class Login extends BrowserOpenClose {

    @FindBy(xpath = "//a[text()='Log In']")
    private WebElement loginLink;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@class='_2zrpKA']")
    private WebElement username;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//input[@class='_2zrpKA _3v41xv']")
    private WebElement password;

    @FindBy(xpath = "//button[@class='_3zLR9i _1LctnI _36SmAs']")
    private WebElement loginButton;

    public Login(WebDriver driver) {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void openLoginDialog() {
        loginLink.click();
    }

    public void enterUsername(String name) {
        username.sendKeys(name);
    }

    public void enterPassword(String pass) {
        password.sendKeys(pass);
    }

    public void clickLogin() {
        loginButton.click();
    }

}

    public class SwitchTShirtPage extends BrowserOpenClose {
    WebDriver driver;
    Login login;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void initElements() {
        login = new Login(driver);
    }

    @Test
    public void switchToTShirt() {
        login.openLoginDialog();
        login.enterUsername("abc");
        login.enterPassword("xyz");
        login.clickLogin();
    }

}
```

> **Error trace log**: java.lang.NullPointerException   at org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.DefaultElementLocator.findElement(DefaultElementLocator.java:69)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.pagefactory.internal.LocatingElementHandler.invoke(LocatingElementHandler.java:38)
>     at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.click(Unknown Source)  at
>   com.login.test.Login.openLoginDialog(Login.java:50)   at
>   com.homepage.test.SwitchTShirtPage.switchToTShirt(SwitchTShirtPage.java:28)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:100)
>     at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:646)   at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:811)    at
>   org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1129)  at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:129)
>     at
>   org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:112)
>     at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:746)    at
>   org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:600)    at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:366)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:361)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:319)   at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:268)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)  at
>   org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)   at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1264)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1189)  at
>   org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1104)     at
>   org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1076)   at
>   org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:126)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:152)
>     at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:57)

Comment: You need to pass super class's (i.e. `BrowserOpenClose`) `driver` reference while instantiating `Login` in `initElements()`, currently you are passing sub class's (i.e. `SwitchTShirtPage`) `driver` reference. Which is not initialized. As as result `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Comment: thank you:) @AtulDwivedi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WebDriver driver` from `SwitchTShirtPage` is never initialized and is always `null`.

What you want is the one from `BrowserOpenClose`, so just remove the declaration from `SwitchTShirtPage`.

Then, be careful because `driver` is initialized with a `@BeforeTest` which is only run once by test (group of classes). So only the first instance of `BrowserOpenClose` will have `driver` initialized.
Consider to replace `@BeforeTest` by `@BeforeClass` which should fix the issue.

Comment: Julien I am in initial stage so used @BeforeTest, later will change to respective annotation. Thanks for your help.